# How to link two columns in an Excel CSV file

Tags: excel

I need to create a database in Excel, what had to be saved as a .csv file. My goal is the following:

For each row in column G. Compare the value with row L if these are the same, copy the values from J->H and K->I. This has to be done for about 45.000 records. Is there a function which can do this for me? I have thought about an 'IF' statement, bus that would mean that I have to next 150 IF statements.

file: https://zuydhogeschool-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/1840398daniels_zuyd_nl/EQuSe2vd0YtJkKwucl6_OZUB4Fl7ODGVzEVQ61T6H0AhuQ?e=fn5egZ

[image: Example]

Comment: If you save the file as csv, then any formula will get written over by its value...

Comment: I know, but I only need the data, not the formulas.I can save those for later use in an separate txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.
Copy this in cell H2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX($L$2:$N$32,MATCH(G2,$L$2:$L$32,0),1)),J2,"")
```

and this in cell I2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX($L$2:$N$32,MATCH(G2,$L$2:$L$32,0),1)),K2,"")
```